# Advantages of wrapping a blocking call which has no callback?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Standard:

```
function myFunc() {
    const hash = crypto.createHash('sha1');
    hash.update(12345);
    return hash:
}
```

Wrapped in a Promise:

```
async function myFunc() {
   const hash = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      try {
        resolve(crypto.createHash('sha1'));
      } catch (err) {
        reject(err);
      }
    });
    hash.update(12345); // <--- Blocking?
    return hash:
}
```

Now, from reading the documentation https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createhash_algorithm it doesn't state callbacks etc.. So, I'm assuming it's a blocking call. Since it is a blocking call and probably has to block, what is the advantage in wrapping it? Since it has to at some point block to create the hash why would I wrap it?

There is a https://github.com/valeriangalliat/crypto-promise module which wraps it.

Comment: I suspect it's usable in a way similar to `Promise.resolve()`, providing a `Promise` interface to the standard methods so they can be used in chains. Other than that, I don't see much benefit in wrapping blocking calls in promises.

Comment: @petkov.np Your pretty much confirming my thoughts, I hope for more peeps to respond too :)

Answer (score 0):

You called the update function on the created `Promise` and returning the `Promise`. This makes no sense, because `update` is not a function of `Promise`.

In a `Promise` you have only two functions, to give back your results. `resolve()` and `reject`.

A `Promise` is an elegant way to handle callbacks.

New way:

```js
const crypto = require('crypto');

/**
 * function returns a promise and you can pass the update value
 * update value must be a string or a buffer
 * @param updateValue
 * @returns {Promise}
 */
const myFunc = (updateValue) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      resolve(crypto.createHash('sha1').update(updateValue.toString()));
    } catch (err) {
      reject(err);
    }
  });
};

// call function with your value
// then gives back the hash object
// catch gives back the error
myFunc(12345).then((hash) => {
  console.log(hash.digest('hex'));
}).catch(err => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Old way, with callbacks:

```js
const crypto = require('crypto');

/**
 * update value must be a string or a buffer
 * two callback function. Success and error handling.
 * @param updateValue
 * @param callbackSuccess
 * @param callbackError
 */
var myFuncCallback = function(updateValue, callbackSuccess, callbackError) {
  try {
    callbackSuccess(crypto.createHash('sha1').update(updateValue.toString()));
  } catch (err) {
    callbackError(err);
  }
}

// call function with your value
myFuncCallback(12345, function(hash) {
  console.log(hash.digest('hex'));
}, function(err) {
  console.log(err);
});
```

async/await

```js
const crypto = require('crypto');

/**
 * async function
 * @param updateValue
 * @returns {Promise}
 */
const myFuncAsync = async (updateValue) => {
  try {
    return await crypto.createHash('sha1').update(updateValue.toString());
  } catch(err) {
    return err;
  }
}

myFuncAsync(12345).then((hash) => {
  console.log(hash.digest('hex'));
}).catch(err => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: I think you missed the `await` call. Which stops the execution until the Promise is resolved. So update isn't called on a Promise but the resolved variable I return.

Comment: But back to the question. Is there an advantage with wrapping it even?

Comment: Callback functions, Promises and async/await are for asynchronous calls. Promises together with async and await makes no sense to me. Its like you use callback functions and promises together. The `Promise` is waiting for a `reject`or `resolve` function call ... Await is also waiting for a callback. https://medium.com/@rdsubhas/es6-from-callbacks-to-promises-to-generators-87f1c0cd8f2e#.9009e9s91

Comment: `async/await `is the newest style, because you haven't nested functions, as it is when you are using promises.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will get benefits when using `myFunc()` in sequence with other code(either blocking or non-blocking).

For example:

```
myFunc();
someFunc();
```

With standard `myFunc()`, it's blocked before `someFunc()` until `myFunc()` got done.

With wrapped `myFunc()`, `someFunc()` will be executed right after `myFunc()` got called.

Comment: This will happen only if the promise executor returns immediately, calling `resolve/reject` in the future. If `resolve(someBlockingOperation())` is called,  the function will of course block and subsequent function calls will wait.